# What's the difference between novalidate and formnovalidate attributes of HTML5?

Tags: forms, html

From w3c schools we have these definitions:

***novalidate***:

> When present, it specifies that the form-data (input) should not be
>   validated when submitted.

***formnovalidate***:

> When present, it specifies that the  element should not be
>   validated when submitted.

Does it make any difference using *formnovalidate* in the **submit button** insted of using *novalidate* in the **form**?

(I really don't get the difference)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`novalidate` is applied to the form, and prevents it from being validated; `formnovalidate` is applied to a submit button, and overrides the `novalidate` option, if present; it means 'submit this form without validating, regardless of the general form setting'.

The example given in the spec is when a user is saving data rather than publishing it; the data might be incomplete and invalid, but doesn't require validation to be saved.

Comment: Formnovalidate can also be used on input elements, so that the whole form validates but not that input element.

Comment: + We're talking about client-side validation (validation in the browser)

Comment: This did not work for me: `<input type="number" name="futureDailyAdSpend" value="138.03" step="50" min="50" formnovalidate/>`. I get this error: "Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 100 and 150."

Comment: @JorisdeRuiter That does not appear to be true, at least not in Chrome. You can't disable validation per-field.