# HTML5 novalidate only for some inputs

Tags: html, validation

I've got really simple question - is there any way to disable HTML5 validation only for some chosen inputs (instead of setting "novalidate" for whole form)?

I mean something like `<input type='number' required`**novalidate**`>`. But this doesn't work.

You may ask why I need type="number" or "required" then? Well, I need it there because my framework uses it for its own validation.

EDIT

It is about one special input - *birth number*. I need it to be of type *number* (because of mobile devices) but its value is mostly used with "/" (e.g. 860518/8757) which is not valid character for type *number*. So I need user to fill it without slash (8605188757). The problem is when there is invalid value filled in html5 input (e.g. "fsda" in number type), it seems like it is empty, with no value.

So when user fill the value in wrong format (860518/8757), html validation is disabled so the JS validation runs, it is validated like empty field. So the error message is like "Please fill the field birth number" (which is really confusing) instead somthing like "Sorry, wrong format".

My solution was to enable html5 validation for this field (so the default browser message is displayed when there is wrong format filled) but disable it for other fields so that they would be validated only with my JS validation.

Comment: `/` symbol doesn't come on keyboard in mobile phone when input type is number.

Comment: @A.J I know, but there is also traffic from PC devices. And lot of people are accustomed to fill this field with `/`. I'd just need some kind of compromise between enabling `/` for number type (this is most likely not possible) and enabling/disabling html5 validation for whole form.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable HTML5 validation for a chosen input(s).

If you want to remove validation on the entire form you can use `formnovalidate` in your `input` element.

For example,

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="button primary large" formnovalidate/>
```

**Note** you can use `formnovalidate` with `<input type=submit>`, `<inut type=image>` or `<button>` -[source](https://www.wufoo.com/html5/formnovalidate-attribute/)

For more info go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761202/whats-the-difference-between-novalidate-and-formnovalidate-attributes-of-html5) or [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formnovalidate.asp).

Comment: This did not work for me: `<input type="number" name="futureDailyAdSpend" value="138.03" step="50" min="50" formnovalidate/>`. I get this error: "Please enter a valid value. The two nearest valid values are 100 and 150."

Comment: @Ryan Well, since you have `step="50"` the values can only be 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, etc, therefore you cannot have a `value="138.03"`

Comment: Here is a better explanation of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522971/html-input-number-step-without-validation#comment78063820_41522971

Comment: `formnovalidate` only works for submit and image inputs, and it disables ALL browser validation.

"formnovalidate HTML51

If the input element is a submit button or image, this Boolean attribute specifies that the form shouldn't be validated before submission. This attribute overrides the novalidate attribute of the element's form owner."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Answer (score 0):

`novalidate` attribute is only for form tag, it can't be applied on form controls.

You can remove the required attribute in js, after your framework validates:

```
$('[Selector]').removeAttr('required');​​​​​
```

*Now the selected field will not be validated.*

Comment: Problem is that my framework JS validation runs right after html5 validation (that's why I have html5 validation disabled by default). Anyway it is not just about "required" attribute. Please look the EDIT of my question.

Comment: @flipis : **/** symbol doesn't come on keyboard in mobile phone when input type is number.

Comment: Down-voted for jQuery, seriously people; the browser *already supports JavaScript*; stop dumping 70KB of I-don't-know-how-to-learn-real-code!

Answer (score 0):

Inputs will be validate when:

1. have attr required or prop required=true
2. aren't empty; don't have to have attr required or prop required=true
3. and have no attr disabled or prop disabled=true

If you want to validate data in a specific way, use pattern attr.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andig89/rbq6m8w0/)

```js
(function() {
    document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
})();
```

```html
<form>
    1. <input type='text'><br>
    2. <input type='text' required><br>
    3. <input type='text' required disabled><br>
    4. <input type='text' value="" pattern="\d*"><br>
    5. <input type='text' value="" pattern="\d*" required><br>
    6. <input type='text' value="" pattern="\d+"><br>
    7. <input type='text' value="" pattern="\d+" required><br>
    8. <input type='text' value="test" pattern="\d+" required disabled><br>
    <button>check field validity</button>
</form>
```